# How can I use the default webcam to capture the photo and save that in my c#.net web application?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, silverlight-4.0

I am working on c#.net based web application. I want to capture user's photo using the default installed webcam on my client's computer. The idea is he capture the photo for my web application and that application is set that in database or directory. Is there a way to do in web application or any other way (by including silverlight module in application)?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/graphics/webcam-and-mic/webcams-(silverlight-quickstart))

Comment: It is better you see my answer link as well. Good than silverlight event.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good solution for my project.

http://shubhamtipstricks.com/2057/capture-image-using-javascript-webcam-and-upload-it-in-your-server/